# In Corona SDK, why is this function returning an error?

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

```
LINE 212   function onCollision(e)
  LINE 213     transition.to(gameView, {time = 300, x = -gameView.height,  display.remove() gameView= nil   



end})

   endGame = display.newImage('end_game_background.png', display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight-   300)


    transition.to(endGame)


background.isVisible = false
lineGroup.isVisible = false




end
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error that says this:
main.lua line:213: '}' expected near gameView

Comment: What a mess, try improve the format of your code. Why is there an `end}`, what is it paired with?

Comment: Please format your code. The community we have is a collection of volunteers who are willing to help. At least respect their commitment by presenting your question in a desirable manner.

Comment: Do you mean for that `display.remove()` to be there?  Looks like a copy-paste error, maybe?

Comment: Proper format will also helps you to understand what you are doing...

Answer (score 3):

```
transition.to(gameView, {time = 300, x = -gameView.height,  display.remove() gameView= nil 

end})
```

is not correct, try `onComplete` or `onCancel`, also use `display.remove(gameView)` instead of `display.remove()`:

```
transition.to(gameView, {time = 300, x = -gameView.height, onComplete=function() 
    display.remove(gameView)
    gameView= nil 
end})
```